# PDO - исполнение запроса с избыточным массивом параметров

Tags: php, pdo

Tакой код работает

```
    $info = array();
    $info[':nik'] = trim($_POST['nik']);
    $info[':phone'] = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $info[':FIO'] = trim($_POST['FIO']);
    $info[':email'] = trim($_POST['email']);

    $sql = "select count(*) from `punbb_users` where `email` = :email limit 1";
    $count = $DB->getOne($sql, array(':email' => $info[':email']));
```

Но если заменить последнюю строку:

```
 $count = $DB->getOne($sql, $info);
```

То уже ничего не работает.

Сама функция `$DB->getOne()` подготавливает и исполняет запрос через pdo

```
public function getOne($sql, $params = NULL) {
    if (is_null($params)) {
        return $this->pdo->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
    }
    else {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }
}

public function prepare($sql) {
    return $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
}
```

Это происходит от того, что нельзя передавать массив с другими параметрами, когда нужен лишь один, или я что-то не так делаю?

Желательна еще и ссылка на документацию, если так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, количество параметров в запросе и в массиве, который передается методу `prepare()` должно совпадать, в противном случае, вам должна возвращаться следующая ошибка

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

Comment: И это никак нельзя исправить? Включение/выключение режима эмуляции может?

Comment: @RussCoder В режиме эмуляции будет такая же ошибка, как вариант - перегружать  execute() в собственном классе и фильтровать входящий массив в нем.

Answer (score 2):

Если идентификатор параметра запроса всегда совпадает с ключом массива $params, то можно было бы немного изменить метод getOne(), используя метод `PDOStatement::bindValue` в цикле:

```
public function getOne($sql, $params = NULL) {
        if (is_null($params)) {
            return $this->pdo->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
        }
        else {
            $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
            foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
                $placeholder = ':'.$key;
                if (strpos($sql, $placeholder) !== false) {
                    $stmt->bindValue($placeholder, $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchColumn();
        }
    }
```